# i-adjectives that end in a 〜ない which doesn't seem to be 〜無{な}い

Tags: meaning, etymology, i-adjectives

I noticed there are many 形容詞{けいようし} (i-adjectives) that end in 〜ない, where the な is not part of the kanji, and doesn't seem to have the meaning 無い.

---

Examples:

- 危{あぶ}ない means "dangerous", while 危 means "danger"
- 少{すく}ない means "few"/"scarce", while 少 means "few"/"little"
- 切{せつ}ない means "heartrending"/"trying", while 切 means "earnest"/"ardent"

(For contrast, examples where it's clearly 無い: 心ない, 情けない, 力ない.)

---

I wonder where exactly this ない is coming from. It is not a classical Japanese ending to my knowledge (like 〜しい).

I speculate that it could be an alternative shortening of the classical Japanese copula 〜なり, but this is odd to me because I suspect the usual shortening of 〜な would be used  if this were the case (as we see in 形容動詞{けいようどうし} (na-adjectives)).

Does anyone know the etymology of these words and/or the meaning of this 〜ない?

Comment: [危ない](http://gogen-allguide.com/a/abunai.html)・[切ない](http://gogen-allguide.com/se/setsunai.html)

Comment: The -nai suffix is defined here: http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=114427700000

Comment: @Dono dead link in the EEA and UK as of 2022

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to snailplane's and Dono's links, it seems that the answer is fairly established:

大辞泉

> 形容詞・形容動詞の語幹など性質・状態を表す語に付いて形容詞をつくり、その意味を強調する

大辞林

> 性質・状態を表す語（形容詞・形容動詞の語幹など）に付いて形容詞をつくり、程度のはなはだしい意を表す

Namely, 〜ない is also a suffix that attaches onto words describing state or quality, turns them into a 形容詞, and emphasizes them.

Comment: Though if someone knows the etymology of 〜ない itself, that'd be pretty interesting to hear :).

Comment: I don't know it well enough to post an answer, but Frellesvig brings up the possibility that ぬ was originally a copula that got converted into an auxiliary, possibly meaning "to be in a given state".  See http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15939893#15939893 and somewhat before / after for a chat mostly between snailboat and me about this ぬ.  If one assumes that the 未然形 was a real thing, ぬ > な（未然形） + ふ（反復・継続の助動詞） forms the なう verb ending, as in おこなう etc.  This adjectival suffix なし has a somewhat similar meaning, and might have a similar derivation.  ぬ might also be the root of なる.

Comment: Nice, I didn't think of that connection!